# solaris + logadm command

Tags: solaris, logging

When I run `logadm` on my Solaris 10 machine I get `exe status - 1`.

My target is to run the command with `exe status - 0`

What do I need to do in order to run my `logadm` successfully and to get `exe status – 0`?

```
  star1a:/ ROOT > /usr/sbin/logadm -rv hw-alarms_2
  # loading /etc/logadm.conf
  # processing logname: hw-alarms_2
  # /etc/logadm.conf unchanged


  star1a:/ ROOT > echo $?
  1
```

Comment: WHY WHY WHY I get (-1) -:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `hw-alarms_2` isn't a defined logname you can't get an exit status of 0 with the command you're using.

Your command

```
logadm -rv hw-alarms_2
```

is asking to have entries corresponding to the log name `hw-alarms_2` removed from the /etc/logadm.conf file.

The exit status of `1` is telling you that an error occurred. The verbose output says that `/etc/logadm.conf unchanged`, this is most likely because you don't have a log name `hw-alarms_2` defined.

---

You do realise that `-r` option to logadm removes the specified logname from logadm.conf don't you ?

> -r
>
> Remove any entries corresponding to the  specified  log-name from the /etc/logadm.conf.

So once you've run your command once successfully it won't do so again unless you change the logname to remove or put the original back in.

e.g. add an entry to logadm.conf

```
logadm -C2 -w mylog /my/really/long/log/file/name
```

delete it

```
logadm -rv mylog
# loading /etc/logadm.conf
# processing logname: mylog
# writing changes to /etc/logadm.conf
echo $?
0
```

Now try and delete it again

```
logadm -rv mylog
# loading /etc/logadm.conf
# processing logname: mylog
# /etc/logadm.conf unchanged
echo $?
1
```

We can't because we previously deleted it. So lets add it back in

```
logadm -C2 -w mylog /my/really/long/log/file/name
```

and delete it again

```
logadm -rv mylog
# loading /etc/logadm.conf
# processing logname: mylog
# writing changes to /etc/logadm.conf
echo $?
0
```

Bingo !

Comment: not clearly , for example logadm -rv hw_alarms_1 was with exe status 0 in spit hw_alarms_1 not exist in logadm.conf  , so why hw_alarms_1 was with exe status 0 and hw_alarms_2 with exe status 1 , both them not defined in the file  logadm.conf

Comment: @yael: what happens if you run `logadm -rv hw_alarms_1` now ?

Comment: sorry my mistake logadm -rv hw_alarms_1 with exe status 1 -:) ,

Comment: It may have existed the first time you ran the command but having deleted it subsequent runs will give an error.

Comment: is it possible to restore the logadm.conf  before the last change ?

Comment: or maybe to run the lofadm with force option ? , my target is to run the logadm with status 0

Comment: @LAIN          -     What a great answer thank you so much , you are a brilliant